# C#: I want to create a statement where depending on the operator entered, subsequent actions will be taken

Tags: c#

If I have Operator 1, Operator 2, Operand, and Result (all textboxes), how would I code this to where if a user Clicks the Calculate button and enters any of the following [/ * + - ] into the Operand the subsequent mathematical actions would occur in which Operator 2 is doing the chosen Operand to Operator 1 and the answer is left in Result.

For example, a user enters "6" into Operator 1, "3" into Operator 2, and "/" into the Operand. Operator 2 is dividing into Operator 1 giving the result of "2". (This is for a homework assignment).

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: "This is for a homework assignment" thats where you lose me. If you had at least tried to do it I would have helped

Comment: @AlexW You shouldn't be answering a question like this even if it isn't homework.

Comment: Programming was "hard" for me to begin with, so I don't mind helping out those who are starting out but only if they show me something they have actually done, even if its a complete mess

Comment: @AlexW Yes, this is part of the assignment.. Not the whole thing.. I am given freedom in my class to code it the I would like. This is not the whole thing simply one part of a larger project that I am working on. I am working from limited knowledge. Since I couldn't get a clear answer online I decided to join stackoverflow to find more knowledgeable people who could help me understand. I didn't want to include my code because for this project I didn't want other users to put the code in my lap by writing it for me with what I have, I wanted suggestions that I can use to work with. :)

Comment: dont be afraid to post code, you'll get a better response if you do

Answer (score 0):

You will have to perform lots of error validation but on basic ground you can use a `Switch` statement for this like

```
switch(operator2)
{
    case "/":
       result = Operand1 / Operand2;
        break;
    case "*":
      result = Operand1 * Operand2;
        break;
    case "+":
      result = Operand1 + Operand2;
        break;
    case "-":
       result = Operand1 - Operand2;
        break;
    default:
       result = 0;
        break;
}
```

Comment: I think OP was looking for the entire solution, winform and all

Comment: @AlexW, Sorry but not up for that. Shown him enough instead that it's a homework question.

Comment: yeah that's why I didn't answer. if OP had at least shown some example of code, I would have helped but I get the impression they've done nothing and want everything.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you for your help! I was previously trying to use if statements for this.. is "case" typically going to better than "if" when trying to define different results for multiple possibilities? (In class, we haven't discussed case but I want to go farther so I'm open to understanding new ways to work with.)